# babel conflict running storybook

Tags: reactjs, storybook

I've an app built with create-react-app. I've added storybook (in accordance to this manual https://storybook.js.org/docs/guides/guide-react/). When I run `yarn storybook`, I get this error.

```
'loose' mode configuration must be the same for both @babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties and @babel/plugin-proposal-private-methods
```

Not quite sure how to solve it. Any ideas?

Comment: Looks like an ongoing issue (there are workarounds): https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/11622 https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/9068

Answer (score 13):

Anybody who has the same issue, this is the best solution (from the link provided by yuriy636). Add this to babel config

```
plugins: [
      '@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties',
      '@babel/plugin-proposal-private-methods',
    ],
```

Comment: For anyone coming across this and still having issues, make sure you have all the relevant `@storybook` packages installed. I was pulling in `@storybook/addons` in my `manager.js` file but didn't have it installed (also had no IDE warnings about it)

Comment: Please update the answear with the extra suggestion or post it as a separate answear, I actually could solve this only thanks to @AdamMThompson fix

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work with the following in babel.config.js:

```
plugins: [
    ["@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties", { loose: true }],
    ["@babel/plugin-proposal-private-methods", { loose: true }],
]
```